# Fallo en solicitud HTTP al usar ESP-NOW

Tags: http, arduino, wifi, esp32

tengo un proyecto que consiste en esp32 que actúan como sensores enviando datos hacia otro esp32 que actúa como nodo central. En este intervienen 2 tecnologías, ESP-NOW para interconectar los esp32, y WiFi para que el nodo central envíe los datos recibidos hacia un servidor.
Por un lado, si utilizo solo ESP-NOW, se envían los datos correctamente entre los esp32.
Por otro lado, si **no** utilizo ESP-NOW, se envían correctamente los datos al servidor.
Ahora, cuando junto ambas tecnologías (ESP-NOW + WiFi) los datos dejan de enviarse al servidor (aunque sí entre los esp32), es decir, funciona ESP-NOW pero no WiFi. Al enviar la solicitud http aparece un error de "connection refused". He leído en diferentes foros que puede haber problemas con estos 2 protocolos simultáneamente, pero en todos el que falla es ESP-NOW y en mi caso es WiFi. Estoy un poco desesperado porque en las soluciones que he encontrado para trabajar con ambos a la vez se hace lo que yo estoy haciendo en mi código, pero no consigo que me funcione. Dejo aquí abajo los códigos que estoy utilizando, a ver si podeis ayudarme por favor.

Muchas gracias!

Código para el nodo central:

```
//CÓDIGO NODO [ESCLAVO EN ESP-NOW] [RECIBE DATOS DE LOS SENSORES Y LOS ENVÍA AL SERVIDOR]

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <esp_now.h>
#include <HTTPClient.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

#define PIN_ZUMBADOR 26
#define PWM_CHANNEL 0

/*Credenciales de la red WiFi*/
static const char* ssid = "iPhone XS de Óscar Gómez";
static const char* pass = "oscargomez";

/*Localización de nuestra API*/
const String API_URL = "http://172.20.10.2:8080";

/*Struct con los datos a recibir. Debe coincidir con la que el maestro envía.*/
typedef struct T_msg {
    long id; // Id del sensor
    double valor;
};
T_msg msg_rx; //Estructura para guardar los datos recibidos


/*Callback ejecutada cuando se reciben datos de algún sensor*/
void OnDataRecv(const uint8_t * mac_addr, const uint8_t *incomingData, int len){ 
  /*Copio el msg recibido en mi struct local y ya puedo hacer lo que quiera con los datos (enviarlos a la API)*/
  memcpy(&msg_rx, incomingData, sizeof(msg_rx));
  Serial.printf("Recibido de: %d \n", msg_rx.id);
  Serial.printf("Longitud: %u bytes\n", len);
  Serial.printf("Valor: %f \n", msg_rx.valor);
  Serial.println();
  doPost(msg_rx);
}


/*Función utilizada para enviar nuevos valores detectados a la API*/
void doPost(T_msg datos_rx)
{
  /*Configuración de la ruta a enviar los datos*/
    HTTPClient http; //Instancia de la clase HTTPClient para realizar la solicitud a la API
    http.begin(API_URL + "/nuevoValor"); //Especificar la ruta a enviar los datos
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); //Cabecera que indica que se está enviando un JSON [opcional]
    
  /*Crear objeto JSON a enviar utilizando la librería ArduinoJson*/
    String msg = "";
  StaticJsonDocument<128> jsonDoc;
  JsonObject json = jsonDoc.to<JsonObject>();
  json["valor"] = datos_rx.valor;
  JsonObject sensorObj = json.createNestedObject("sensor"); //createNestedObject añade un nuevo objeto JSON al jsonDoc
  sensorObj["id"] = datos_rx.id;
  serializeJson(jsonDoc, msg); //convertirlo a cadena

  /*Realizar solicitud POST enviando el objeto JSON serializado. Este método devuelve el código de respuesta HTTP.*/
    int httpResponseCode = http.POST(msg);

  /*Leer la respuesta del servidor*/
  String response = http.getString();

  Serial.println("Response Code: " + httpResponseCode);

    
  if(httpResponseCode > 0) { //Si respuesta HTTP válida...
        Serial.printf("Response code: %d\t", httpResponseCode );

        if(response == "Activar alarma") {
      //Hacer sonar la alarma!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      sonarAlarma();
    }
    }
    else { //Si ha habido algún error, se imprime el error por pantalla.
        Serial.printf("Request failed, error: %s\n", http.errorToString(httpResponseCode ).c_str()); //errorToString para obtener una descripción del error
    Serial.println();
    }
    http.end(); //Liberar los recursos utilizados por la solicitud HTTP.
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); //Iniciamos el terminal Serial a 115200 baudios (símbolos por segundo)

  /*Configuración zumbador*/
  pinMode(PIN_ZUMBADOR, OUTPUT); //pin zumbador como salida
  ledcSetup(PWM_CHANNEL, 0, 10); //Nº canal PWM, su ciclo de trabajo[0 pq no es necesario con la función ledcWriteTone] y bits de resolución
  ledcAttachPin(PIN_ZUMBADOR, PWM_CHANNEL); //Asignar pin del zumbador al canal PWM configurado

  /*Ajustes WiFi*/
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA); //Configurar dispositivo como estación WiFi y como AP

  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass); //Iniciamos la conexión a la red WiFi definida
  Serial.print("Conectando a red WiFi "); //En el terminal Serial, indicamos que se está realizando la conexión
  Serial.println(ssid);
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) //Mientras se realiza la conexión a la red, aparecen puntos
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  //Conexión realizada correctamente. Imprimimos algunos datos importantes(IP asignada al ESP32 y MAC del esclavo[para ESP-NOW])
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("WiFi conectado correctamente.");
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.print("MAC address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.macAddress());

  /*Inicializar ESP-NOW*/
  if(esp_now_init() != ESP_OK) {
    Serial.println("Error inicializando ESP-NOW");
    return;
  }

  esp_now_register_recv_cb(OnDataRecv); //Registramos la callback a lanzar cuando se reciban datos [BUCLE INFINITO INTERNO QUE ESPERA SIEMPRE RECIBIR DATOS]

  Serial.println(WiFi.channel());
}

void loop() {
}


void sonarAlarma() {
  float sinValue;
  int toneValue;
  unsigned long startTime = millis(); //Tiempo actual en milisegundos
  while (millis() - startTime < 5000) { //Sonar durante 5 segundos
    for (int x = 0; x < 360; x += 1) {
      sinValue = sin(x * (PI / 180));
      toneValue = 2000 + sinValue * 500;
      ledcWriteTone(PWM_CHANNEL, toneValue);
      delay(1);
    }
  }
  ledcWrite(PWM_CHANNEL, 0); //Detener el sonido después de 5 segundos
}
```

Código para uno de los sensores:

```
//CÓDIGO SENSOR [MAESTRO EN ESP-NOW] [ENVÍA DATOS AL ESCLAVO]

#include <WiFi.h>
#include <esp_wifi.h>
#include <esp_now.h>

#define ID_SENSOR 1 //Id del sensor devuelto al registrar un nuevo sensor en la app android

#define PIR_PIN 25 //pin del esp32 donde está conectada la salida del sensor PIR [ver diagrama de pines]

bool aviso_enviado = false; //Variable para evitar que se envíen varios avisos para un solo movimiento

/*SSID de la red WiFi (aunque el maestro no se conecte a la red WiFi, es necesario el SSID para encontrar el canal en que trabaja la red (que será el mismo que usa el maestro))*/
static const char* ssid = "iPhone XS de Óscar Gómez";

/*Dirección MAC del esclavo[nodo] (es única y está preprogramada en el dispositivo)*/
uint8_t slaveAddress[] = {0x30, 0xAE, 0xA4, 0x28, 0xA3, 0x60};

/*Struct con los datos a enviar. Debe coincidir con la que el esclavo espera.*/
typedef struct T_msg {
    long id; // Id del sensor
    double valor;
};
T_msg msg;

esp_now_peer_info_t slaveInfo; //Estructura para configurar registro del esclavo[nodo]


/*Callback ejecutada cuando se envían datos para mostrar en el Serial si se han enviado o no correctamente*/
void OnDataSent(const uint8_t *mac_addr, esp_now_send_status_t status){
  Serial.print("\r\nEstado del último paquete enviado:\t");
  if(status == ESP_NOW_SEND_SUCCESS)
  {
    Serial.println("Datos enviados correctamente");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Error al enviar datos");
  }
}

/*Función que encuentra el canal en que está trabajando la red WiFi*/
int32_t getWiFiChannel(const char *ssid) {
  if(int32_t n = WiFi.scanNetworks()){
    for(uint8_t i=0; i<n; i++){
      if(!strcmp(ssid, WiFi.SSID(i).c_str())){
        return WiFi.channel(i);
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); //Iniciamos el terminal Serial a 115200 baudios (símbolos por segundo)

  pinMode(PIR_PIN, INPUT); //el pin actúa como entrada para recibir los datos del sensor PIR

  /*Ajustes WiFi*/
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); //Configurar dispositivo como estación WiFi (aunque el sensor no se conecta al WiFi, ESP-NOW funciona en la capa MAC del WiFi, por lo que debe configurarse)
  int32_t channel = getWiFiChannel(ssid); //Obtenemos canal de la red WiFi. Lo queremos porque como ESP-NOW funciona sobre WiFi, necesitamos que este utilice el mismo canal WiFi que el maestro para evitar interferencias y que el esclavo escuche siempre el mismo canal.
  esp_wifi_set_channel(channel, WIFI_SECOND_CHAN_NONE); //Lo establecemos en este maestro. WIFI_SECOND_CHAN_NONE indica que no se utilizará un canal secundario(para que siempre se use el primario y se eviten interferencias)
  Serial.printl("Canal: " + channel);

  /*Inicializar ESP-NOW*/
  if(esp_now_init() != ESP_OK){
    Serial.println("Error inicializando ESP-NOW");
    return;
  }

  esp_now_register_send_cb(OnDataSent); //Registramos la callback a lanzar cuando se envíen datos
  
  /*Registrar peer esclavo[nodo]*/
  memcpy(slaveInfo.peer_addr, slaveAddress, 6);
  slaveInfo.encrypt = false;
  
  if(esp_now_add_peer(&slaveInfo) != ESP_OK){
    Serial.println("Error al registrar el peer esclavo");
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("Configuración e inicialización correctas.");
}
 
void loop() {
  /*Recogida y envío de datos*/
  double pirValue = digitalRead(PIR_PIN); //1[movimiento] o 0[no movimiento]
  if(pirValue == 1 && !aviso_enviado){ //si detecta movimiento y aun no se ha enviado aviso, envía un aviso al esclavo
    msg.id = ID_SENSOR;
    msg.valor = pirValue;

    if(sizeof(msg) > ESP_NOW_MAX_DATA_LEN){ //nunca va a ocurrir, pero por prevenir en usos futuros...
      Serial.println("Error: los datos son demasiado largos para enviar por ESP-NOW.El máximo es de 250B.");
      return;
    }

    /*Enviar mensaje por ESP-NOW*/
    esp_now_send(slaveAddress, (uint8_t *)&msg, sizeof(msg)); //la comprobación de si se envía o no correctamente la hace la callback definida para ello

    aviso_enviado = true;
  }
  else if(pirValue == 0 && aviso_enviado){ //[para cuando deja de detectar movimiento]: si no se detecta movimiento pero había un aviso enviado, es que se ha dejado de percibir ese movimiento y si se vuelve a detectar alguno, es uno nuevo
    aviso_enviado = false; //lo ponemos a false para que si vuelve a detectar entre en el primer if
  }
  
  delay(1000); //La comprobación de movimiento se realiza cada 1 segundos
}
```